# Using global variables in WinUI apps

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, winui-3, c++-winrt

I'm trying to create a desktop app using C++ and WinUI 3. This app contains multiple windows/pages, and I would like to use only one instance of a Client class everywhere in the app.

Is there a quick/easy way to do so? I tried to pass the client between pages using the OnNavigatedTo function, but it seems too unpractical.

```cpp
// example
    void ConnectionPage::OnNavigatedTo(Navigation::NavigationEventArgs const& e)
    {
        m_client = winrt::unbox_value<Pine::PineClient>(e.Content());

    }
```

I can't manage to put my client in the App class either, as it has no corresponding MIDL file and I can't access its members that are not in by default from my other pages. (like `Resources`, `OnLaunched`, `RequestedTheme` etc...).

I can't find anything talking about this kind of problem online, can anyone guide me?

Thanks

Comment: "Using global variables in WinUI apps" - Short answer: *Don't*. Don't use global variables. Period. If you do, you'll be sorry eventually.

Comment: Then am I supposed to create one client instance for every single page of my application? This would create a lot of superfluous traffic over my server, as clients need to authenticate with it.

Comment: There are other options. Variables don't need to be global in order to be shared.

Comment: Then that's what I'm searching for. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Probably the most natural place for it is in your top-level page (the one that has the navigation frame).

Comment: This method didn't seem very practical either, as it requires me to do this `Parent().as<Controls::Frame>().Parent().as<Controls::NavigationView>().Parent().as<Pine::HomePage>().Parent().as<Controls::Frame>().Parent().as<Pine::MainWindow>().Client();`

Comment: `Window::Current().Content().as<MainWindow>().Client()`.

Comment: [This function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.current?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#microsoft-ui-xaml-window-current) actually doesn't work. It almost looks like they want people to use global variables? Anyways, do you still have any ideas?

Comment: Then you can walk up the parent chain until you find the MainWindow class. I think the problem is that WinUI allows you to have multiple windows per thread, so `Window::Current()` is ambiguous. The more traditional solution is to put the state in an explicit Model.